# SendOnly mode with no local queue

Tags: nservicebus

In NServiceBus you can create a SendOnly bus which means that all it will do is send messages to another service. It seems to me that this should not require a local queue for the sending service at all, however i have been unable to configure this.

```
var bus = Configure.With()
    .DefiningCommandsAs(t => typeof(MyNamespace.Messaging.Markers.ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
    .UnicastBus()
    .SendOnly();
```

gives the following exception:

> No endpoint name could be generated, please specify your own
>   convention using Configure.DefineEndpointName(...)

While i can solve this issue by adding a `.DefineEndpointName` it seems like poor form to be creating a queue for this service as it will never actually be used.

*Is there a way of avoiding needing to create a local queue for a send only bus, and if not why is this local queue required in this mode?*

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a DoNotCreateQueues() or similar that is available, what happens if you add that?

Comment: @AdamFyles I didn't know that was there and it looks really promising, but unfortunately i still get the same error after adding it into the config.

Comment: That should work without `.DefineEndpointName(...)` (tested against v3.3.5), see [sendonly sample](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/SendOnlyEndpoint/SendOnlyEndpoint.Custom/Program.cs).  What version of NServiceBus are you running?

Comment: @JohnSimons thats really interesting, im running 3.3.0 at the moment. Im going to try this in a console app and see if i can get it going too... The above is in a MVC site (not that that should make a difference)

Comment: @JohnSimons I see what the issue is but im still not sure of the why, I have a custom command interface (I didn't put it in the question as i didn't think it was relevant but it appears to be). Any idea why this would make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All endpoints needs a name regardless if they are send only or not. This has nothing to do with the creation of queues(yes the queue name == endpoint name). Add a define endpoint name and you'll see that no queue will be created. Also note that the sent messages will not contain a reply to address since that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: that's interesting that it doesn't create a queue, why does it not require .DefineEndpointName if i don't use .DefiningCommandsAs? I also noticed that when sending with no .DefineEndpointName it does reference a sender queue that doesnt exist.

Comment: my guess is that by skipping the convention no messages is found and that doesn't trigger this issue with the endpoint name. I need to check to code to be sure

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is provide where the message came from. The sending queue is an intrinsic part of MSMQ. It allows for ack messages, supports the NServiceBus bus.Reply feature.

In this case is it seems unnecessary, but if we consider that SendOnly is trying to guide the developer towards using a particular messaging style. Considering that MSMQ which supports many styles of messaging, this isn't such an issue in my view.

Comment: That makes sense, it still seems a little ugly but i get why :)